# The same method for class and instance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have class `Books` and method `select` in it. Also there is an instance of that class called `book`. I want to be able to do both `Books.select(where='...')` and `book.select(where='...')`:

```
class Books():
    def select(obj, where):
        print(obj, where)

book = Books()
Books.select(where='asdf')
book.select(where='asdf')
```

The above obviously doesn't work, because `select` is an instance bound method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    Books.select(where='asdf')
TypeError: select() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

A working code:

```
class Books():
    @staticmethod
    def select(obj, where):
        print(obj, where)

book = Books()
Books.select(Books, where='asdf')
Books.select(book, where='asdf')
```

And i get:

```
vic@wic:~/projects/snippets$ python3 test.py 
<class '__main__.Books'> asdf
<__main__.Books object at 0x17fd6d0> asdf
```

But i have to manually pass the class or its instance as the first argument to the `select` method - not what i want.

If i make `select` a class method:

```
class Books():
    @classmethod
    def select(obj, where):
        print(obj, where)

book = Books()
Books.select(where='asdf')
book.select(where='asdf')
```

I always get a class as the first argument:

```
vic@wic:~/projects/snippets$ python3 test.py 
<class '__main__.Books'> asdf
<class '__main__.Books'> asdf
```

But i want to get an instance in the second case.

So, is there a way to accomplish what i want without manually passing the class/instance as the first argument to a static method?

Comment: Yes, but you'll want to shoot yourself.

Comment: :) thanks for the prediction :) I think the way to go is to make my own decorator to replace `classmethod`.

Comment: If you are going to call `select` as a static method, and you are not going to explicitly pass the object in the method call, what will you use for `obj` when you go to print it?

Comment: Not a decorator, a descriptor.

Comment: i don't want to use `select` as a static method - that's the issue. if i use `classmethod` i lose instance. If i don't use `classmethod` or `staticmethod` - i cannot call the method from a class.

Comment: Don't do this. Don't use the same method to do two wildly different things depending on if it's called on the class or on the instance. It's a Bad Idea (tm) and you will confuse both yourself and everyone else. Besides, what would `book.select()` do? It's only one book, you can't really select anything.

Comment: i am writing an ORM. Books is a Table subclass. Books(where_expression).select() is meant to return a set of books (another class). But i want also to have possibility to do Books.select(where_expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class Select(object):
    def __get__(self,obj,objtype):
        x=objtype if obj is None else obj
        def select(where):
            print(x,where)
        return select
class Books(object):
    select=Select()

book = Books()
Books.select(where='asdf')
book.select(where='asdf')
```

yields

```
<class '__main__.Books'> asdf
<__main__.Books object at 0xb7696dec> asdf
```

Comment: Be careful with `obj` being false even though it's not `None`.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** using a descriptor and a decorator:

```
class class_or_instance_method():
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        x = obj or objtype
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.method(x, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped        

class Books():
    @class_or_instance_method
    def select(obj, where):
        print(obj, where)


book = Books()
Books.select(where='asdf')
book.select(where='asdf')
```

Result:

```
<class '__main__.Books'> asdf
<__main__.Books object at 0x2695890> asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example I founded on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52304-static-methods-aka-class-methods-in-python/

You create a little wrapper:

```
class Callable:
    def __init__(self, anycallable):
        self.__call__ = anycallable
```

And then defines your class and a class variable inside it.

```
class Class2:
    def static2(name):
        print "Hi there",name
    static2 = Callable(static2)

# now, a call such as:
Class2.static2("Peter")
# works just fine, and as-expected
```

Comment: He wants to get the class as the auto-argument if called on the class, and the instance if called on the instance.