# Duck typing and class methods (or, how to use a method from both a class and an instance?)

Tags: python, class-method, duck-typing

I have some code which I would like to pass instances or classes interchangeably. All I will do in that code is to call a method that I expect both classes and instances to have (the method `go()` in the example below).

Unfortunately, I can't create a classmethod with the same name of a regular method... See example below. I initially expected the second call to produce an `a` instead of a `b`.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class A(object):
...     def go(self):
...             print "a"
...     @classmethod
...     def go(cls):
...             print "b"
... 
>>> a=A()
>>> a.go()
b
>>> A.go()
b
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why can't you put all of your code in a classmethod? Or, if not, have two separate classes? Or always pass instances with default values?

Comment: you can't assign 2 different methods/propierties to the same name, is like trying to stick 2 numbers into an integer variable.

Comment: This isn't duck typing. Duck typing is expecting two separate classes - which don't necessarily share an ancestor - to have the same methods.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Exactly! ``a`` has the class ``A``. And ``A`` has the class ``type``... They *are* separate classes, which don't necessarily share the same ancestor :)

Comment: @Marcin Can you give an example of how those options would work?

Comment: @KurzedMetal I realize that now, but the need remains... hence, my request for advice on possible alternatives :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750896/the-same-method-for-class-and-instance

Comment: @FilipeCorreia I can't give an example until I know what you are trying to achieve. In any case, they are simple concepts - which part do you not understand?

Comment: @warwaruk That's a good reference, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider reusing the `classinstancemethod` decorator from formencode.

https://bitbucket.org/formencode/official-formencode/src/06d52c5b33c9/formencode/declarative.py

```
class classinstancemethod(object):
    """
    Acts like a class method when called from a class, like an
    instance method when called by an instance.  The method should
    take two arguments, 'self' and 'cls'; one of these will be None
    depending on how the method was called.
    """

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return _methodwrapper(self.func, obj=obj, type=type)


class _methodwrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, func, obj, type):
        self.func = func
        self.obj = obj
        self.type = type

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        assert 'self' not in kw and 'cls' not in kw, (
            "You cannot use 'self' or 'cls' arguments to a "
            "classinstancemethod")
        return self.func(*((self.obj, self.type) + args), **kw)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.obj is None:
            return ('<bound class method %s.%s>'
                    % (self.type.__name__, self.func.func_name))
        else:
            return ('<bound method %s.%s of %r>'
                    % (self.type.__name__, self.func.func_name, self.obj))
```

Comment: `self` will be `None` if called via class. But I'm not sure `cls` will be `None` fi called via instance - I think this is only valid for Py3. In Py2, the class will be given even in the instance case.

Comment: Did so. Output were the lines `i: <__main__.A object at 0xb74976ac> <class '__main__.A'>` and `c: None <class '__main__.A'>`.

Comment: Whatever, maybe you just submit a patch to formencode to fix the comment. Anyway, it does what you asked.

Comment: Just tested under Py3 - it gives the `cls` as well in both cases. Nevertheless, it was not me who asked :-)

Comment: Changed it, but I am not allowed to push, and there is no bug tracker enabled in this repo.

Comment: Thanks. The other solutions cam really close, but I'm accepting this one as it seems more robust.

Comment: @ddaa I've noticed you edited the question title to make clearer. I still think it makes sense to have "duck typing" in there somewhere though, because that's how I first thought about it, and I'm sure others might think about it that way too. In python, both classes and instances are... instances. So it makes sense for me to think of this as duck typing. Do you agree?

Comment: I think people familiar with programming language design would not consider this duck typing because classes and instance live at different levels in the metaclass hierarchy. Feel free to edit the title and tags if you think that would make the questions easier to find.

Comment: @ddaa But if they are, like here, used iterchangeably, and thus "are used on the same level", the term is ok again IMHO. YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an own method type with a specially crafted `__get__()` method.

In this method, you could do something like this:

```
class combimethod(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
    def classmethod(self, func):
        self._classfunc = classmethod(func)
        return self
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self._classfunc.__get__(instance, owner)
        else:
            return self._func.__get__(instance, owner)

class A(object):
    @combimethod
    def go(self):
        print "instance", self
    @go.classmethod
    def go(cls):
        print "class", cls

a=A()
print "i:",
a.go()
print "c:",
A.go()
```

NOTE: The above is not very thoroughly tested, but seems to work. Nevertheless, it should be seen as a kind of "solution-near pseudo-code", not as a solution. It should give you an idea how to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
import inspect

class A(object):
   @staticmethod
   def go(obj):
      if inspect.isclass(obj):
         print 'class'
      else:
         print 'instance'

A.go(int) # class
A.go(1)   # instance
A.go(A)   # class
A.go(A()) # instance
```

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty close, but I have to pass the class itself as an argument, which is not exactly what I was looking for.