# Is is possible to make a class method that is also a instance method?

Tags: python, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The same method for class and instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750896/the-same-method-for-class-and-instance)
>   [Use a method both from a class and from an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413488/use-a-method-both-from-a-class-and-from-an-instance)

I am working on a project where we have test cases written in python. In some test cases
we do most set up in setUpClass and in some in setUp. For example we prepare data in a database. We have helper methods that populate the database and such. What I would like is
methods that works both as a classmethod and a instance method. For example:

```
class TestBase(object):

    def insertStuff(self, data):
        self.cursor.execute(...)

# Usage 1, class
class Test1(TestBase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.insertStuff([1, 2, 3])

# Usage 2, instance
class Test2(TestBase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.insertStuff([1, 2, 3])
```

This won't work since insertStuff is not a class method. If we change it around make it a class method Usage 2 won't work.

Of course we could make it a static method that takes either class or instance as a parameter, but I find that quite ugly and would rather do it in some nicer way if possible.

At least I would like to know if it is possible or not to make me stop thinking about it.
I want the test cases to be clear and easy to read, if there is a solution that is ugly
in the base class I can live with that.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your example. Is `cursor` an instance variable, or a class variable? If you chose one, insertStuff will not be well defined on the other.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? How can the exact same operation apply to classes and instances? If you simply call a classmethod on an instance, the method receives that instance's class. Is that what you want?